# Access list of attributes in attribute constructor

Tags: .net, properties, attributes, .net-4.5, propertygrid

A similar question has been asked few times before, and I know that attributes don't, in general, work that way, but here's what I want to achieve, if such behavior is possible.

I want to create class:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class AutoDescriptionAttribute : System.ComponentModel.DescriptionAttribute
{
    public AutoDescriptionAttribute(string description) : base(description)
    {
        base.DescriptionValue = GetDescription();
    }

    private string GetDescription()
    {
        return /*Get, somehow, informations about other applied attributes*/
    }
}
```

That attribute, when applied, should set description for property based upon other attributes (and their values) decorating that property, so there's no need to write separate descriptions for every property, but just add an AutoDescription attribute.

I'm wondering if it's possible to do that, or maybe some different approach, but what is important to me, is:

1. To have one attribute that causes different descriptions for different attributes
2. Use standard PropertyGrid, i.e. not to have to create huge PropertyGrid derivative that does something with properies and their attributes (as was achieved in some projects I've seen over the net).